# R.java creating illegal value

Tags: android, r.java-file

In my R.java file I am getting error on this line

```
public static final int  =0x7f08000a;
```

I have not modified the R.java. Please advice.

Comment: Try cleaning your project again, also may be you could restart eclipse and check if that helps.

Comment: I have restarted eclipse,system and cleaned project serval times

Comment: @downvoter, please tell the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R.java displays error without changing in it, may be issue with your resources. Resources file's name must not contain **-**, **capital letter of file name**, try to check it after it clean the project and try to build, thanks.